# How do I pool objects in a parallel process pool?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pool

I have a function that does calculations with the help of a mutable object as in the example below:

```
def fun(obj: MutableObject, input_a, input_b):
    obj.a = input_a
    return obj.do_stuff(input_b)
```

I need to do this many times and am currently using a for loop as seen below:

```
obj = MutableObject()
output = []

for input_a, input_b in inputs:
    output.append(fun(obj, input_a, input_b))
```

To speed the process up I want to use python multiprocessing and perform multiple calls of `fun` in parallel. A common way I have seen this done is by using `multiproccesing.Pool` to map over a list. The problem for me with such an implementation is that I have the mutable object that needs to be shared between the processes. I would like each process to have access to a clone of the object without creating unnecessarily many clones.

A naive attempt would be to copy the object for each input:

```
import multiprocessing
import copy

obj = MutableObject()
def map_fun(arg):
    input_a, input_b = arg
    temp_obj = copy.deepcopy(obj)
    return fun(temp_obj, input_a, input_b)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
outputs = pool.map(map_fun, inputs)
```

But that seems wasteful, both on CPU and memory.

Is there any way I can create a temporary pool of object copies, one for each parallel process, instead of creating one for each input pair?

EDIT:

It was pointed out in a comment that memory probably won't be an issue as the garbage collection will clean up the unused copies. I am still worried that copying will require lots of recourses though as my MutableObject in reality is a Keras model (neural network) that can be quite large.

Comment: do you *have* to have the function mutate an object?  Can you abstract the cpu intensive logic away from mutating the object?  What you describe is possible, but on first thought it's a bit of an antipattern, at least without more data

Comment: I don't have control over how the mutable object is implemented as it is from a third party. More specifically it's a keras model.

Comment: But the object gets reset when the function is called again?  so the idea is to have n objects for n threads, and have every thread use its object?

Comment: The provided code seems to create a copy of the object for each process.  How is this different from "create a temporary pool of object copies, one for each parallel process"?  I think you are already doing that.

Comment: @2e0byo

The object is only changed by the explicit changes such as obj.a = input_a. The function obj.do_stuff() does not have side effects.

You are correct on my idea. That's the best idea I have come up with so far. But maybe there are other ways of doing it that are equally ore more efficient.

Comment: @KotaMori It creates one copy for each input. There could potentially be thousands of inputs but I do not think that there are thousands of processes running at the same time in that case. I might be wrong though.

Comment: @EmilJansson If the object is not used any more after each process, then the garbage collection will throw that away. This usually happens automatically, but you can also explicitly execute the garbage collection with gc parckage. https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html  This may help you avoid creating thousands of copies.

Comment: @KotaMori This is true and it does limit the issue regarding memory. The object still needs to be recreated though which I think might be computationally intensive. I should probably add a statement regarding the object being a keras model (neural network) in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which drops the pool and manages the threads itself, ensuring only one object for each process:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, cpu_count, JoinableQueue


class MuteableObj:
    def method(self, data):
        data["processed"] = True
        return data


class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        super().__init__()
        print("Started", self._name)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self._obj = MuteableObj()
        self._open = True

    def run(self):
        while self._open:
            task = self.task_queue.get()
            print(f"Processing {task['id']}")
            result = self._obj.method(task)
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            self.result_queue.put(result)
        print("over")

    def terminate(self):
        print("Stopped", self._name)
        super().terminate()


task_queue = JoinableQueue()
result_queue = JoinableQueue()

NTHREADS = cpu_count()

for i in range(200):
    task_queue.put(dict(id=i))


threads = [Worker(task_queue, result_queue) for i in range(NTHREADS)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

task_queue.join()

for t in threads:
    t.terminate()

results = []
while not result_queue.empty():
    results.append(result_queue.get())

print(results)
```

Firstly we have a mock of your muteable object, here just a class with one method we care about.

We subclass `Process` ourself, and give each process one object at initialisation.  Then we fill a `JoinableQueue` with the required tasks, and wait until they are all done, when we get all the results out of another queue (although we could actually use a list and `Lock`, but I think this is easier to read).

Note that results are not guaranteed to be in the order in which they were sent.  If this matters, you should give them an id as I have here, and sort by the id.

If you need to the pool to run indefinitely and do specific things with each result, you probably want to write a callback, move the `join()` to the end of the code (since it blocks until all tasks are processed) and then have a loop which waits for results and calls your callback:

```py
from time import sleep

while running:
    while not results_queue.empty():
        callback(results_queue.get())

    while results_queue.empty():
        sleep(0.1)
```

In this case I would wrap all this up in *another* class, called something like `TaskRunner`, to keep state (like `running`) isolated.

Incidentally I first came across this recipe on SO years ago, and I've been using it ever since.

Comment: Thank you, this looks fantastic. I will try it out and mark your answer as accepted if everything works out!