# Why does unpickling several files in parallel using a Pool object "freeze"?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I was trying to unpickle several files in parallel; however, the process just "hangs."

First, I create 6 small pickle files:

```
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Pool

class A:
    x: int
    y: str
    
    def __init__(self, x:int, y:str):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

for i in range(6):
    with open(str(i) + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(A(i, str(i) + 'abcdefg'), f)
```

Next, I try to load them in parallel:

```
def load(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)

with Pool(6) as p:
    p.map(load, [str(number) + '.pkl' for number in range(6)])
```

When I launch this from Spyder, all 8 logical processors (4 "actual" cores) show close to 100% utilization in Windows Task Manager; however, the process does not terminate. If I try to stop the process from Spyder, it fails to do so; the only way to stop it is to close Spyder entirely.

However, if I do this in a normal `for` loop, it takes a fraction of a second:

```
for file in [str(number) + '.pkl' for number in range(6)]:
    load(file)
```

Can someone explain why this is? Also, is there some way to fix the original code such that it actually works? (The files I'm *actually* trying to load and process are much larger, which is why I would like the parallelism; the above code is just an example to help people reproduce the issue).

I have read several Q&As related to loading with pool, such as [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69468304/how-do-i-pool-objects-in-a-parallel-process-pool); however, none of them helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using multiprocessing you have to include the **main** check [see this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)

So something like this will work for you:

```
import pickle
from multiprocessing import Pool

class A:    
    def __init__(self, x:int, y:str):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
def make():
    for i in range(6):
        with open(str(i) + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(A(i, str(i) + 'abcdefg'), f)

def load(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)

def main(): 
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(load, [str(number) + '.pkl' for number in range(6)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    make()
    main()
```